# Flask app isn't updating the front end templates

Tags: python, heroku, flask, deployment, devops

I have a flask app which has some front end static files (in React). However whenever I make changes to the HTML, it doesn't reflect it on the browser. I pushed it to my github and everything is correct on my github but when I go to the browser, it still has my old changes.

I tried starting the server but it hasn't helped. I pushed the code to Heroku and it's the same issue. You can take the look at the website [here](http://kaisinli.com). And you can see on my [github](https://github.com/kaisinli/flask-portfolio), the HTML for Home.jsx (my job) and Protfolio.jsx are clearly different.

Comment: Which assets/changes are not reflected? Have you tried clearing your browser cache before loading the page?

Comment: @IainShelvington so for example, on my home page, it says my job is Quality EDGAR but on my actual file (as seem on my GIthub) it says Signafire. I tried using Chrome Incognito and it didn't work

Comment: `public/bundle.js` has not been updated in in 2 years and still has the old home page code. You need to run a webpack build to update `bundle.js`

Comment: @IainShelvington yes you're right, thank you!